# MySQL Transposition

Tags: mysql

Hi everybody and happy new year !

I have a Mysql table like this :

```
date | endpoint | nb200 | nb500
d1   | toto     | 11    | 12
d1   | tata     | 13    | 14
d1   | tutu     | 15    | 16
d2   | toto     | 21    | 22
d2   | tata     | 23    | 24
d2   | tutu     | 25    | 26
```

For each date, each endpoint is unique, and so i have a unique key (date, endpoint). date column are real date, but for example, d1 and d2 should be great.

Now, i would like to write a select request that show me the nb200 results like this :

```
date | toto | tata | tutu
d1   | 11   | 13   | 15
d2   | 21   | 23   | 25
```

For now, my best try is

```
SELECT date,
  (CASE WHEN endpoint = 'toto' THEN nb200 END) AS 'toto',
  (CASE WHEN endpoint = 'tata' THEN nb200 END) AS 'tata',
  (CASE WHEN endpoint = 'tutu' THEN nb200 END) AS 'tutu',
FROM table;
```

But this is not so good because i get the following :

```
date | toto| tata| tutu
d1   | 11  |     | 
d1   |     | 13  |
d1   |     |     | 15
d2   | 21  |     |
d2   |     | 23  | 
d2   |     |     | 25
```

Does someone has any idea about how to do this ?

Comment: you can group by date

Comment: use `max` on `nb200` and group by `date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT `date`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN endpoint = 'toto' THEN nb200 END) AS 'toto',
  MAX(CASE WHEN endpoint = 'tata' THEN nb200 END) AS 'tata',
  MAX(CASE WHEN endpoint = 'tutu' THEN nb200 END) AS 'tutu'
FROM mytable
GROUP BY `date`
```

`MAX` is used in order to selectively get each one of the `endpoint` values.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65214e/4)

Answer (score 1):

you could use (fake) aggregation function and group by

```
  SELECT date,
    min(CASE WHEN endpoint = 'toto' THEN nb200 END) AS 'toto',
    min(CASE WHEN endpoint = 'tata' THEN nb200 END) AS 'tata',
    min(CASE WHEN endpoint = 'tutu' THEN nb200 END) AS 'tutu',
  FROM table
 group by date;
```

Comment: min works too, and without the second "END))" parenthesis, it work fine.